# how to get the previous url in flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am using flask to do some user interaction. Basically, when the user clicks a button on page A or B, it goes to url C to get some data which does not have a visualization. After getting the data, I want to go back to the original page (A or B). How shall I find out where the user came from?

Comment: Maybe, you can do it on client side with js function window.history.back()

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think what you need is **request.referrer**. There are some examples [here](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/76929/flask.request.referrer)

Comment: I want to see implementation of `is_safe_url` function you have in the example.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz [`django/utils/http.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/http.py#L285-L304)